# GitLab CI Runner fails to pull private Docker image w. "no basic auth credentials" but it works via SSH

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci, amazon-ecs, gitlab-ci-runner

I've looked through related issues on SO and this does not appear to be a duplicate.

When GitLab CI Runner pulls an image from AWS ECR it fails with this error:

```
ERROR: Preparation failed: API error (500): \
  Get https://***.dkr.ecr.***.amazonaws.com/v2/***/manifests/latest: no basic auth credentials
```

But I've set up the machine with ECR credentials, I can SSH into it and both `root` **and** `gitlab-runner` users can pull the image. This all used to work fine up until recently, but I've no idea what might've changed.

What does "no basic auth" even imply?

To be specific, these are the steps I've done:

- Start a plain AWS EC2 Linux instance, and SSH into it

Then:

```
sudo su
echo -e "\n\nexport http_proxy=http://www-proxy.internal.novastone.net:3128\nexport HTTP_PROXY=http://www-proxy.internal.novastone.net:3128\nexport https_proxy=http://www-proxy.internal.novastone.net:3128\nexport HTTPS_PROXY=http://www-proxy.internal.novastone.net:3128" >> ~/.bashrc
echo -e "\n\nexport http_proxy=http://www-proxy.internal.novastone.net:3128\nexport HTTP_PROXY=http://www-proxy.internal.novastone.net:3128\nexport https_proxy=http://www-proxy.internal.novastone.net:3128\nexport HTTPS_PROXY=http://www-proxy.internal.novastone.net:3128" >> /home/ec2-user/.bashrc
yum update -y
yum install -y docker
mkdir ~/.docker
echo -e "{\n    \"proxies\": {\n        \"default\": {\n            \"httpProxy\": \"http://***:3128\",\n            \"httpsProxy\": \"http://***:3128\"\n        }\n    }\n}\n"> ~/.docker/config.json
echo -e "export http_proxy=http://***:3128\nexport HTTP_PROXY=http://***:3128\nexport https_proxy=http://***:3128\nexport HTTPS_PROXY=http://***:3128\n" > /etc/sysconfig/docker
service docker start
usermod -a -G docker ec2-user
docker pull hello-world  # To verify basic functionality
curl -s https://packages.gitlab.com/install/repositories/runner/gitlab-ci-multi-runner/script.rpm.sh | bash
yum install -y gitlab-ci-multi-runner-1.11.5-1.x86_64
usermod -a -G docker gitlab-runner
pip install awscli --upgrade --user
aws configure
$(aws ecr get-login --no-include-email --region ***)
docker pull ***.dkr.ecr.***.amazonaws.com/***:latest  # To verify ECR works
gitlab-ci-multi-runner register
exit # Drop back to ec2-user
sudo -u gitlab-runner bash
echo -e "\n\nexport http_proxy=http://www-proxy.internal.novastone.net:3128\nexport HTTP_PROXY=http://www-proxy.internal.novastone.net:3128\nexport https_proxy=http://www-proxy.internal.novastone.net:3128\nexport HTTPS_PROXY=http://www-proxy.internal.novastone.net:3128" >> /home/gitlab-runner/.bashrc
aws configure
$(aws ecr get-login --no-include-email --region ***)
docker pull ***.dkr.ecr.***.amazonaws.com/***:latest  # ECR works here as well
```

At this point ECR image is shown to work in all users. I've completely bypassed our proxy as far as I can tell by setting env. variables permanently for all users, Docker can pull fine in any SSH situation, and et the `no basic auth credentials` persists when GitLab Runner gets involved.. why? Any theories at all? All help or thoughts appreciated!

EDIT: FWIW [I've also asked on the GitLab forum](https://forum.gitlab.com/t/gitlab-ci-cant-pull-docker-images-no-basic-auth-credentials/15215).

Answer (score 2):

It is likely that the linux user owning the Gitlab process does not have the required credentials. You can test this by running `sudo -u <username> -H <command>`

Alternatively, you can pass `--user` parameter to the runner command to use a linux user that can login to ECR.

Comment: Yeah Runner is using user `gitlab-runner`, who does not natively have access to Docker and so can't log it into ECR. But I've done that (exposed `docker.sock` + binary), and made `docker pull` work from it, but GitLab Runner still show the same error. Also, I can find no articles suggesting this as the primary cause. It's a good suggestion, but I've come to believe it is not the correct approach.

Comment: It felt like a nasty hack to expose Docker into the user, and it didn't use to be necessary. But happy to try more possibilities, do you know how I can change the user? This is on AWS Linux and I'm still looking for where it specifies the --user flag.

Comment: Did you try using the `--user` option with the `gitlab-runner`?

Comment: Well, I don't know where actually. And googling hasn't helped me yet. I can see the flag is used with `ps aux`, but [*hangs head in shame*] I don't know where on AWS Linux that value is passed to the service.

Comment: See Step 5 in https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/install/linux-manually.html. Looks like the runner is installed with the `--user` flag.

Comment: Thanks! I've reconfigured it to use root and.. same result :(. `ps aux` shows it runs w. `--user root`. I find that surprising.

Comment: Can you try setting `--user` to the linux user that is able pull the image on the command line? Setting it to root does not help because the auth token to the ECR repo is not available to root. Unless of course, you were using root on the command line before when it worked.

Comment: Oh, yes I've been root all along, root is where `docker pull` works. Docker should only be exposed to root user, no? I think that's why Gitlab Runner runs as root, but uses a sub-user to invoke specific runs, I imagine it's temporarily piping docker socket to that user to allow it to operate it.

Comment: Just to say I've enabled Docker for user `gitlab-runner`, I can log in and pull. But `gitlab-ci-multi-runner` still shows `no basic auth` failure.

Comment: FWIW I've updated my question with the specific steps I've taken. This should make it clear how I use `root` and how I deduce what works via SSH.

Answer (score 1):

I got working my GitLab runner with AWS ECR access.
I used Ubuntu18 AMI and used the below script in user-data of ec2 configuration or script can be run as root in by ssh into the server.
Attach role to EC2 instance with enough ECR access permission.

Gist link: `https://gist.github.com/piyushsonigra/6f67210aefcbee8071f46dc764fa8936`

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e
apt update -y && apt install awscli make -y
curl -LJO https://gitlab-runner-downloads.s3.amazonaws.com/latest/deb/gitlab-runner_amd64.deb
dpkg -i gitlab-runner_amd64.deb
sed -i -e '/volumes/s/\["\/cache\"]/\["\/cache","\/var\/run\/docker.sock:\/var\/run\/docker.sock"]/' /etc/gitlab-runner/config.toml
curl -fsSL https://get.docker.com -o get-docker.sh && sh get-docker.sh && usermod -aG docker gitlab-runner
gitlab-runner register \
  --non-interactive \
  --url $GITLAB_URL \
  --registration-token $TOKEN \
  --executor "docker" \
  --docker-image "docker:latest" \
  --description "gitlab-runner" \
  --tag-list "gitlab,runner,aws" \
  --run-untagged="true" \
  --locked="false" \
  --access-level="not_protected"
echo -e "export AWS_SDK_LOAD_CONFIG=true \nexport AWS_REGION=$REGION >> ~/.bashrc
source ~/.bashrc && mkdir ~/.docker
cat <<EOF >>~/.docker/config.json
{
  "credsStore": "ecr-login"
}
EOF
git clone https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-ecr-credential-helper.git
cd amazon-ecr-credential-helper/ && make docker 
cp bin/local/docker-credential-ecr-login /usr/local/bin/
systemctl restart docker  && gitlab-runner restart
export AWS_REGION=$REGION && docker-credential-ecr-login list >> ~/.ecr-url.log
```

Last command output we should get as ECR URL to in ~/.ecr-url.log

Then you can run commit or run pipeline with .gitlab-ci.yml file at root directory of repo. 
Below is the sample code for .gitlab-ci.yml to test pipeline.

```
image: aws_account_id.dkr.ecr.REGION.amazonaws.com/IMAGE_NAME:latest

build:
  stage: build
  script:
  - echo "hello"
```